# Multiple initialization steps issue in UIViewController (cannot use multiple inheritance)

Tags: ios, swift, multiple-inheritance, swift-protocols

I am trying to implement a UIPageViewController with some initialization steps encapsulated in another base class.

As multiple inheritance is impossible in Swift, I am trying to go with protocols but I would like to trigger some initialization steps encapsulated in a base class.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/michael-martinez/75a464a1719093a66e728094bd34457b) is the base controller I wrote.

It encapsulates Facebook Account Kit plugin to hide connection infos that should not be seen from my child VC (e.g. the import AccountKit directive, the AKFAccountKit class instance).

When I use that in a standard class it works :

```
class ClientViewController: AccountKitBaseViewController { /*...*/ }
extension ClientViewController: AccountKitBaseViewControllerDelegate {/*...*/}
```

But I cannot use it if I use a PageVC as client class :

```
class ClientViewController: UIPageViewController, AccountKitBaseViewController { /* Error: Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIPageViewController' and 'AccountKitBaseViewController'*/ }
extension ClientViewController: AccountKitBaseViewControllerDelegate {/*...*/}
```

How can I manage to do it ?

Comment: You can't.. Instead, you can implement your protocol on an extension with constraints and use object-association to allow storing properties in the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to advice you put all logic from `AccountKitBaseViewController` to some assistant class and add instance of this class to your controllers. It will help you to avoid code duplication. You can use the following assistant class:

```
class SocialNetworkAssistant {

    //Put here all required propertie from AccountKitBaseViewController
    public var delegate: AccountKitBaseViewControllerDelegate?
    public var isUserLoggedIn: Bool = false
    private var _accountKit: AKFAccountKit!
    private var _pendingLoginViewController: AKFViewController?

    //Put here all required methods from AccountKitBaseViewController
    public func accountKitLogout(completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {

        guard isUserLoggedIn == true else { return }

        isUserLoggedIn = false
        _accountKit?.logOut()
        completion?()
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

And then you can put instance of `SocialNetworkAssistant` in your controllers:

```
class ClientViewControllerFirst : UIViewController, AKFViewControllerDelegate {

    private let socialNetworkAssistantInstance = SocialNetworkAssistant()

    /* AKFViewControllerDelegate methods implementation */
}

class ClientViewControllerSecond : UIPageViewController, AKFViewControllerDelegate {

    private let socialNetworkAssistantInstance = SocialNetworkAssistant()

    /* AKFViewControllerDelegate methods implementation */
}
```

You can also use the bridge pattern. Make `SocialNetworkAssistant` as a base class for all classes that will implement `AKFViewControllerDelegate` instead of your controllers. Then you will use different subclasses of `SocialNetworkAssistant` in your controllers.